# What is wrong with this code?

Tags: plotting

I am plotting polar curves with `PolarPlot` and I tried plotting a parabola with $\frac{2}{1-\cos x}$ and $\sec x$.

Obviously there are two singularities that have to be considered, $\cos x=1$ and $\cos x=0$. I dont know how to specify multiple singularities for the same function or variable. This is what I have tried so far:

```
PolarPlot[{2/(1 - Cos[x]), Sec[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Exclusions -> {Cos[x] == 0, 1}]

PolarPlot[{2/(1 - Cos[x]), Sec[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Exclusions -> {x == 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/2, (3 \[Pi])/2}]

PolarPlot[{2/(1 - Cos[x]), Sec[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Exclusions -> {Cos[x] == 0, Cos[x]==1}]
```

What is the right way to do this?

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could just specify a `PlotRange`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VvfsJ.png

Comment: @RahulNarain but in your image too there are errors how can i rectify them...??

Comment: @RahulNarain how to put the exclusions, that would achieve the same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have expected your last form to work. Avoid the issue by putting the exclusion points {-Pi/2, 3Pi/2} at the boundaries of the iterator.

```
PolarPlot[{2/(1 - Cos[x]), Sec[x]},
 {x, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 20}, {-10, 10}},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

EDIT: Supposition about behavior of `Exclusions -> Automatic`.

```
$PerformanceGoal
```

> "Quality"

From the documentation for `Exclusions`: "`Exclusions -> Automatic` is effectively equivalent to `Exclusions -> True` if `$PerformanceGoal` is 'Quality', and to `Exclusions -> None` otherwise. `Exclusions -> True` excludes all subregions where discontinuities are found in functions being plotted." For the function `2/(1 - Cos[x])` the discontinuities are easy to detect; however, the discontinuities in `Sec[x]` are apparently too subtle for whatever algorithm is used and are overlooked unless they are at the iterator boundaries. Presumably, the functions are evaluated at the iterator boundaries and when the singularities of `Sec[x]` are at the boundaries, they are discovered and excluded.

Comment: thank u for your solution very helpful

Comment: Why is it that if we put exclusion points at the ends the function misbehaves ?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Thank you, for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly enough, there are no errors if you change the order of the two functions, and it doesn't seem to require any explicit exclusions:

```
PolarPlot[{Sec[x], 2/(1 - Cos[x])}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}]
```

[image: evaluated plot]

As Rahul Narain suggested, I also added a plot range.

Answer (score 3):

my best effort at that plot, manually clipping the angle range:

```
 Show[{
      PolarPlot[ 2/(1 - Cos[x]), {x, .1, 2 Pi - .1} ,
         AspectRatio -> 1 , PlotStyle -> Red  ],
      PolarPlot[Sec[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi} , AspectRatio -> 1 ]},
         PlotRange -> {{-5, 20}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]

after playing with this a bit I've concluded `PolarPlot` is simply badly behaved regarding `Exclusion` and even `PlotRange` options.

If we make that first range `{0,2 Pi}` the curve disappears all together, unless we specify some large number for `PlotPoints` :

```
 Show[{
     PolarPlot[ 2/(1 - Cos[x]), {x, 0, 2 Pi} ,
      AspectRatio -> 1 , PlotStyle -> Red  , PlotPoints -> 2000],
     PolarPlot[Sec[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi} , AspectRatio -> 1 ]}, 
          PlotRange -> {{-5, 20}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]

The curve fills in if you make `PlotPoints` even larger..not a very satisfactory solution though.

Answer (score 1):

The `RegionFunction` option allows you to parametrically define what portion of the function to plot

```
PolarPlot[2/(1 - Cos[x]), {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> 30 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, \[Theta], r}, r <= 25]]
```

[image: output graphics]